# Continuous function of a squarerooted value

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

So, I even displayed the solution but didn't quite get it. How is it that $\sqrt[3]{x+1}$ defined for all real numbers, while with $\sqrt[4]{x+1}$ x has to be $x+1\ge 0$?

[question and its solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDX77.png)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, but notice how $x^3$ can be negative but $x^4$ cannot be negative for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any real number has a real cube root.

  For example, $\sqrt[3]{8}=2$, and $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$.

More generally, for odd positive integers $n$, any real number has a real $n$-th root.

But for even positive integers $n$, only nonnegative real numbers have real $n$-th roots.

  For example, $\sqrt{9}=3$, but $\sqrt{-9}=3i$, which is non-real.

Thus, for the expression $\sqrt[3]{x+1}$, there are no restrictions on $x$.

However, for the expression $\sqrt[4]{x+1}$, the expression $x+1$ must be nonnegative, so the needed restriction is $x \ge -1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think like this:

Taking roots is the inverse operation of exponentiation. So $\sqrt[4]{x}$ means which number $k$ should I raise to the power of $4$ to get $x$? And similarly for higher roots $\sqrt[3]{x}$ means which number $l$ should I cube to get $x$?

Now when you square something (taking fourth power is squaring twice) you always get something non-negative, so when you find the number $k$ above you will square it to get $x$ therefore $x$ has to be non-negative.

For odd exponents, let us use the example above, we seek $\sqrt[3]{x}$ that is we need a number $l$ which cube is $x$, and when you are cubing you can get any real number so therefore in this case we have no restriction about the sign of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because that $1^4$ and $(-1)^4$ are equal to one. $(-1)^3$ is equal to -1. $(-1)^4=((-1)^2)\cdot((-1)^2)=1\cdot1=1$ but $(-1)^3=((-1)^2)\cdot-1=1\cdot-1=-1$. That means, if x=2: $\sqrt[4]{x+1}=\sqrt[4]{-2+1}=\sqrt[4]{-1}=i$ but not $1$ or $-1$, and $\sqrt[3]{x+1}=\sqrt[3]{-2+1}=\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$. Same applies for all $x\le-1$(4th root(x) is imaginary or complex, 3rd root(x) has 1 real root).